# Argument passed from Main App to Library project with Gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I have one library project which contains a ContentProvider, because there is no possibility to use the same AUTHORITY within multiple app (expected behavior) I am asking if there is a way that the library will use an argument given by the main app project.
It will permits me to change dynamically the AUTHORITY string from the app project.
But for now, I didn't find any trick to do such a thing with Gradle.

Is it possible, or am I obliged to create a buildVariant for each App within the library project ? Because it's the only trick I've found for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any solution to do such a thing with Gradle, but I found a possible workaround thanks to this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/14592121/1312889.