# Android application conflicting INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-library

I am designing one SDK for using in multiple applications. In my application, I am using `ContentProvider`. While I am using that SDK in two applications I am getting `INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER` error.

First application does not have any issue. While I try to install the second application using that same SDK I am getting this error. Any Idea how to use Content Provider in SDK?

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Is your provider exported?

Comment: Are you defining URI in both applications? Uri can not be same for two apps.

Comment: Refer this answer by @CommonsWare http://stackoverflow.com/a/10791144/1468093